# How to host multiple .Net application using same Public id but in different port?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

can you please help me to host multiple dotnet application build in dotnet web form and asp.net mvc using IIS. To bind port for each application. so, they can be accessed using public IP instead of using Public ip and application extension.

[image]

I tried hosting both application on default port . Its working but have to type application name while URL. I want to type public IP and their corresponding port respectively.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use hostnames? You can't really use TLS without a hostname, and most browsers will disable lots of useful (if not essential) web-features unless the page is loaded [from a secure-context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts).

Comment: ports are bind to websites. so if you want applications under same site - that would not be a ports. to utilize ip/port - you need to create a separate websites with proper port bindings.

Comment: How do you publish multiple .Net applications to iis? If you want to use a different port, you just need to add a different port in the Site Binding.

Comment: I even created on inbound rule for port 81. After that, I try to access that network from another computer but it not working.  so my question is, How can i host multiple dotnet applications in iis so that I can access them from another network? I even try binding ports separately its working in local but not working in public network

Comment: Host multiple dotnet applications and access them from another network are two different problems, you can try it first, and then discuss it when you encounter any problems, there will be many similar problems on the Internet.